# Finding Descendant Depth in an Adjacency List Table

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, hierarchical-data

**Question**

Example Table

```
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
| category_id | name                 | parent |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   NULL |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |      1 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |      2 |
|           4 | LCD                  |      2 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |      2 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |      1 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |      6 |
|           8 | FLASH                |      7 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |      6 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |      6 |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
```

Given the example table above, I'm thinking in Oracle I should be able to write SQL along the lines of "SELECT ... CONNECT BY" to find the level of a given id. For example, "MP3 Players" has a LEVEL of 3.

Example borrowed from [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

**Solution**

```
SELECT MAX(level) "LEVEL"
FROM TEST_TABLE
START WITH category_id = 7 -- MP3 Players category_id
CONNECT BY category_id = PRIOR parent
ORDER BY LEVEL DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `level` pseudocolumn to get the "depth" of the current row. Consider the following statement:

```
SELECT category_id, name, level,
 PRIOR name as parent_category
FROM test_table
START WITH parent is null
CONNECT BY PRIOR category_id = parent
```

Comment: This is step in the right direction: more specifically I'm looking for the SQL that gives me the level of a particular id (e.g. 7). After doing some additional searching on my own I've added the solution I came up with to the initial question.